# CSS Buttons at same Level

Tags: css

[image]

In this pic as you see, I want to have these buttons at the same level regarding the text above them. Each of them in different div but they have the same class name since I am using drupal for that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Absolute positioning, or flexbox.

Comment: Or two divs with fixed heights, or tables (no, I'm kidding), or ...

Comment: Always post some code if you want help.

Comment: its a jcarousel in Drupal its a group of divs with the same classes

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative;` for red background element. Assign following properties to `button`.

```
{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
}
```

Comment: Assign `position:relative` to its parent

Comment: I add position:relative still having the a problem in the shape a postion of these buttons when they scroll in the JCarousel

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I'm guessing you would do something like this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.column {
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex: 1 1 0;

}
```

```html
<div class = "container"> 
<div class = "column"> <p>foo foo foo</p><button> button</button></div> 
<div class = "column"> <p>foo foo bar

foo foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo
foo foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo
foo foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo
foo foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo
foo foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo

foo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar</p><button> button</button></div> 
  <div class = "column"> <p>foo RAHA RAHAHAR</p><button> button</button></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: it dosnot work for me! I have millions of divs inside each other.